# VB.NET call desktop application from 2 shortcuts - supply different parameters

Tags: vb.net, desktop-application, shortcut

I have a desktop application which reads files from a specified folder, then deposits the files to a folder in a third party document management system based on criteria that the user provides.

My question is:

is it possible to somehow provide different parameters to the code, depending on which shortcut of the application the user clicked on to start it up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add command line parameters to a shortcut icon.  Here's how you can do it in Windows:

- On the Start Menu, navigate to Notepad.
- Right click on Notepad and choose Send To > Desktop (Create Shortcut)
- Right click on the newly-created desktop icon and choose Properties
- Add your command line parameters to the Target text box.

  - For example, if you want notepad to open up the hosts file, this would be the content of Target property:

    > %SystemRoot%\system32\notepad.exe "C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts"

You can put pretty much anything into the Target property of a shortcut that you would put into a command line.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

The easiest way would be to have the shortcut pass those parameters in via the command line.

Comment: can you explain how i would do that? IE, where would i write the code,and what kind of code would i be writing?

Comment: I dont know if i was clear, but the user will not start the application via the commnad line. they will need to start it from a desktop icon.
thanks

Comment: @user I added an answer that I think answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use conditional compilation variables, and have 2 different .exes.  You should be able to find samples of both approaches (command line and conditional compilation variable) in help.

Comment: MS help files embedded into the product, online samples, Microsoft's knowledge base, or Google.